# How to import contact list from yahoo API with C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, winforms, contacts, yahoo-api, import-contacts

I have Windows Desktop Application and i want to import Contacts from Yahoo.
Is there any solution to import contacts from yahoo directly?.Since, YQL and OAuth are the option for Web development. 
[Google provided an API for import contacts from gmail](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters). which is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
I got my answer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91646/Implementing-Yahoo-Contact-Reader-Using-ASP-NET 
Since, Yahoo provide security all you need to do a Domain verification first.
rest worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo did not provided any API for importing contacts through API. You can make use of REST to communicate with API - a good article of [Implementing Yahoo Contact Reader In ASP.NET and CSharp](http://www.yogihosting.com/blog/implementing-yahoo-contact-reader-in-asp-net-and-csharp/) will be helpful to you.
Thank You